# Magento 2: What is Difference between Create & Get ObjectManager?

Tags: magento2, object-manager, magento2.1.5

I have below code. Which give same result either I use `create` or `get`

```
$orderId = 1;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$this->orderPayment = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface')->load($orderId);
$this->orderPayment = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface')->load($orderId);
echo $this->orderPayment->getLastTransId();
```

So What is exactly difference between them? Which needs to be used & when?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **$_objectManager->create()** creates new instance of the object, no-matter-what
- **$_objectManager->get()** first tries to find shared instance (already created), if it's not found - it just creates new shared instance

If you take a look at class ***Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager***, you'll notice this block:

```
...
/**
 * Create new object instance
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param array $arguments
 * @return mixed
 */
public function create($type, array $arguments = [])
{
    $type = ltrim($type, '\\');
    return $this->_factory->create($this->_config->getPreference($type), $arguments);
}

/**
 * Retrieve cached object instance
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @return mixed
 */
public function get($type)
{
    $type = ltrim($type, '\\');
    $type = $this->_config->getPreference($type);
    if (!isset($this->_sharedInstances[$type])) {
        $this->_sharedInstances[$type] = $this->_factory->create($type);
    }
    return $this->_sharedInstances[$type];
}
...
```

Comment: create () is like "new Class()" and get () is like 'Mage::getSingleton()', it will first check the same class instance is exists or not in memory. If the instance is created then it will return the same object from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use object manager (bad practice).

You have to pass `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` in construct of your class.

```
    protected $order;

    public function __construct(
        ..., 
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $order
    ){
        ...
        $this->order = $order;
    }
```

Then you can do following:

```
$order = $this->order->get($orderId);
echo $order->getPayment()->getLastTransId();
```